# How to pass collection data from Python to bash?

Tags: python, bash

I am writing a dev ops kind of a `bash` script that is used for running an application in a local development environment under configuration as similar to production as possible.  To eliminate duplicating some code/data which is already in a `Python` script, I would like my bash script to invoke a Python call to retrieve data that is hard coded in that Python script.  The data structure in Python is a dict but I really only care about the keys so I can just return an array of keys.  The Python script is used in production and I want to use it and not duplicate the data in my shell script to avoid having to follow on any modification in the production script with parallel changes in the local environment shell script.

Is there any way I can invoke a Python function from bash and retrieve this collection of values?  If not, should I just have the Python function print to STDOUT and have the shell script parse the result?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is best and almost only way to pass data from python to bash.

Also your function can write to file, which would be read by bash script.

Answer (score 1):

To write a Python dictionary from a module out to a NUL-delimited key/value stream (which is the preferred serialization format if you want to represent the full range of values bash is capable of handling):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, yourmodule
saw_errors = 0
for k, v in yourmodule.data.iteritems():
    if '\0' in k or '\0' in v:
        saw_errors = 1 # setting exit status is nice-to-have but not essential
        continue       # ...but skipping invalid content is important; otherwise,
                       #    we'd corrupt the output stream.
    sys.stdout.write('%s\0%s\0' % (k, v))
sys.exit(saw_errors)
```

...and to read that stream into an associative array:

```
# this is bash 4.x's equivalent to a Python dict
declare -A items=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' key && IFS= read -r -d '' value; do
    items[$key]=$value
done < <(python_script) # where 'python_script' behaves as given above
```

...whereafter you can access the items from your Python script:

```
echo "Value for hello is: ${items[hello]}"
```

...or iterate over the keys:

```
printf 'Received key: %q\n' "${!items[@]}"
```

...or iterate over the values:

```
printf 'Received value: %q\n' "${items[@]}"
```

---

**Caveat:** Python bytestrings (regular strings, in Python 2.x) are Pascal-style; they have an explicit length stored, so they can contain any raw binary data whatsoever. (Python 3.x character strings are also Pascal-style, and can also contain NULs, but the aforementioned sentence doesn't quite apply as they don't contain raw binary content -- while the next one still does). Bash strings are C strings; they're NUL-terminated, so they can't contain raw NUL characters.

Thus, some data which can be represented in Python cannot be represented in bash.

Comment: Argh. First version was using `print` rather than `sys.stdout.write()`, and thus leaving extra newlines in the output.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could make a python script that prints out a bash array.

bashify.py

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from sys import argv
from importlib import import_module

def as_bash_array(mapping):
    return " ".join("[{!r}]={!r}".format(*item) for item in mapping.items())

def get_mapping(name):
    module, var = name.rsplit(".", 1)
    return getattr(import_module(module), var)

executable, mapping_name = argv

mapping = get_mapping(mapping_name)

print "(", as_bash_array(mapping), ")"
```

usage:

```
declare -A my_arr="`./bashify.py my_module.my_dict`"
```

Using `!r` in the format string means non-printing characters such as `NUL` will be escaped (`"\x00"` for `NUL`). It also means that string values will be quoted -- allowing characters that would otherwise break the array declaration syntax.

Comment: That's `repr()`-type quoting? It's not compatible with shell representation -- for instance, `"\x01"` in bash is four bytes; it needs to be quoted using `$''` style, as in `$'\x01'`, to be a single byte, but Python (of course) doesn't know that. Likewise for `\r`, `\n`, etc.

Comment: ...and simply prepending a `$` to the repr() output doesn't work, as `$""` is a different thing entirely (and double-quotes will be used for any value containing literal single-quotes).

Comment: ...also, Python's repr can be trivially manipulated to use double-quotes rather than single-quotes from someone who controls the input data, which has more effects on interpretation in shell than in Python. `"''$(rm -rf /)''"` might be harmless here, if command substitutions aren't processed, but being able to change the quoting type definitely _does_ increase the number of factors in play.

Comment: All that said, I _do_ think this answer can be corrected, and with fairly little work -- using `pipes.quote()` in Python 2.x, or `shlex.quote()` in Python 3.